# Largest alternating subsequence of 1s and 0s in a string

Tags: java, string, binary

Find largest alternating 1s and 0s sub-sequence in a `String` containing only 1s and 0s. Also find the starting index for the largest sub-sequence.

Example:

For 1101011, the longest alternating sub-sequence length is 5, from index 1 to 5.

I tried doing it by comparing consecutive elements and if they are not equal, comparing current length to max size:

```
int findSubArray(int arr[], int n) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    int maxsize = -1, startindex = 0;
    int endindex = 0;

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)  {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i+1] && maxsize < i - j + 1) {
            maxsize = i - j + 1;
            startindex = j;
        } else {
            j = i;
        }
    }

    endindex = startindex+maxsize-1;
    if (maxsize == -1)
        System.out.println("No such subarray");
    else
        System.out.println(startindex+" to "+endindex);

    return maxsize;
}
```

Testing the method:

```
int [] ia = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
findSubArray (ia, 7);
```

Returns: 5 and prints 0 to 4

The problem is that although it prints correct length, which is 5, the indexes are incorrect. Correct Output should be 1 to 5.

To rectify this, if I do `j = i + 1`, then the whole matching goes for a toss and I get the indexes as 0 to 0.

What is the mistake in the above code? Also, any pseudo code for an alternative approach would help.

Comment: What's with the *-3 down vote favorite Find largest alternating 1s and 0s subsequence in a string containing only 1s and 0s*?

Comment: and why the python tag?

Comment: Are you asking on Stackoverflow about a code golf?

Comment: Looks like OP asked this before but it was deleted: [original quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755748/how-to-find-largest-alternating-subsequence-of-1s-and-0s-in-a-string), and [google cached question](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xjsI10Sr_EYJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755748/how-to-find-largest-alternating-subsequence-of-1s-and-0s-in-a-string+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct in changing `j = i;` to `j = i + 1;`, but it wasn't enough.

What you are missing is that the current alternating series begins at `j` and ends at `i+1`, not `i`.

In addition, there is a problem in the logic of your condition. Your else clause should be reached only when the current alternating sequence ends (i.e. `arr[i] == arr[i+1]`) but it is also reached when the current sequence is not longer than the max sequence.

Therefore the condition should be broken into two conditions:

```
if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]) {
    if (maxsize < i + 1 - j + 1) {
        maxsize = i + 1 - j + 1;
        startindex = j;       
    }
} else {
    j = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: I think still there's a problem with logic. After adding this modification, for an input  int arr[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};  I'm getting the maxsize as 3 and index from 2 to 4. The maxsize should be 4 and index from 2 to 5

Comment: @AnkitGupta yes, the logic was still incorrect. See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah. understood. that solves the issue. Thanks. Do you think is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @AnkitGupta You're welcome. You can make it more readable if you use meaningful variable names (for example, instead of `j`), but in terms of performance there's nothing to improve - you are iterating over the array exactly once, and you can't do better. Perhaps you can get rid of the `n` parameter, since that's equal to `arr.length`, which makes it redundant.

Comment: Yes I will make the variables names meaningful. Thanks for your help Eran

Answer (score 0):

```
int findSubArray(int arr[], int n) {
    if(n<=0){
        return 0;
    }
    int maxLen = 1;
    int prevPos = -1;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        maxLen = max(maxLen, i-1-prevPos);
        if(arr[i-1] == arr[i]){
            prevPos = i-1;
        }
    }
    maxLen = max(maxLen, n-1 - prevPos);
    return maxLen;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).